# Best way to define an Array's initial data after it's already been instantiated in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that's already been instantiated in the objects class (a.k.a. prototype) with new Array(), but has no data.  After creating an object, I usually define its initial data all at once.  Is there a way to assign all this data without doing 100 individual lines of push?  Is there a way to assign a large amount of data to an existing array at once?  Perhaps something like:

```
myArray.push([1,2,3]);
```

I could use:

```
myArray = myArray.concat([1,2,3]);
```

but that creates an entirely new array, which seems more expensive and messy when all I'm really doing is assigning an existing array its initial data.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: If you have an Array on the `.prototype`, you should be aware that it will be shared among all instances unless you manually give each instance its own Array. In other words, you almost never want an Array or Object on the constructor's `.prototype`.

Comment: (Not related to your question, but) Note that `myArray = [];` is nicer than `myArray = new Array();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're talking about an *existing* array, you don't need several calls to `.push()`. You can pass several arguments in one call.

```
myArray.push(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
```

---

If the items to be added are in a different Array, you can use `.apply` to add them individually.

```
var itemsToAdd = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

myArray.push.apply(myArray, itemsToAdd);
```

---

But for a *new* Array, use either the literal syntax to create and initialize at the same time, or you can pass multiple items to the Array constructor.

In your question you state that the Array is on the constructor's `.prototype`. As I noted in the comment above, that's usually not what you want. But if it is intended to be shared in this case, then the first two solutions above will work.

Comment: Great!  Just what I was looking for.  For more consideration, I created a little test to see how performance compared on different methods: [http://jsperf.com/assigning-data-to-an-array](http://jsperf.com/assigning-data-to-an-array).  Obviously, direct assigning is vastly superior in performance, but I didn't think it would be that significantly better.  I also learned to never use concat.

Answer (score 1):

I think I don't understand the question but if the array is actually empty you could just asign the values to the old one changing the reference and letting the garbage collector to remove the empty one:

```
var array = new Array()
// Later on your code
array = [1, 2, 3];
```

Having said that, it's better to not do this and initialize your array when you have data to add into.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't much reason to instantiate an empty array before you intend to use it for something, especially if you are just going to load in data later. In your example, you could just skip the initialization completely.

```
// leave it undefined initially
var array;

// set it to your values
array = [1,2,3];
```